# Can't get rid of top navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an iPhone app with an all-custom GUI. I had placeholder UINavigation elements before but have since added my own buttons and set up all the segues programmatically. Now I am ready to get rid of the navigation bars and just use my own buttons but they won't go away. I have disabled them in the storyboard but they still show up. How to I get rid of them without removing the Navigation Controller entirely?

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard editor, uncheck the "Shows Navigation Bar" property on your UINavigationController. Ensure you don't re-enable the property in code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do it programmatically:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

This approach allows you to hide/show the navigation bar from the view controllers of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard editor, uncheck the "Shows Navigation Bar" property on your UINavigationController. 
OR do it programmatically:
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];